# Should you use tasks and mutex/semaphore in multiple device drivers that share a bus?

Tags: task, driver, semaphore, rtos

I'm writing a set device drivers for an RTOS that share a single hardware bus. It seems like a bad idea to have tasks running in each device driver that shares this resource because, hierarchically, they are on the same level. Also they have no knowledge of when the other driver may try to access the bus. So wouldn't it be cleaner and more robust to have the functions that access the drivers be task synchronized at the application layer to avoid this bus contention?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must implement some form of resource synchronization to prevent tasks from accessing the resource simultaneously and interfering with another task's use of the resource.

Yes, you can use a mutex to protect the resource from multiple concurrent accesses.  Every task should get the mutex before using the resource and then release the mutex when finished with the resource.  This way a task that needs the resource will block waiting for the mutex if the resource is in use by another task.  A mutex is a better tool than a semaphore for this use-case because a mutex is designed such that only the owner can release it.

An alternate design is to create one task that is responsible for all accesses to the resource.  Other tasks must send requests to the resource task via an inter-task communications mechanism such as a mailbox or queue.  This way the resource usage gets synchronized by having to go through the resource task's queue.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was really helpful. It was requested that I create a mutex that is used amongst the drivers. I think that's a bad idea because if a task runs that uses the driver, the driver takes the mutex but doesn't finish before the scheduler comes along, the task using the driver gets put on the stack and the the mutex never gets released. Now the next task is blocked because the mutex was never released.

Comment: @user1452627 You have some misconception. Assuming correct programming, the mutex will be released when the task regains control and finishes using the resource.  That's the whole idea.  If tasks were not allowed to switch while one uses a resource, then a mutex would be pointless.

Comment: If the mutex to the shared resource isn't released in task1 because of the scheduler, and task2 runs, and the first line in task2 is getMutex(WAIT_FOREVER), how can task2 run? I thought the point of a mutex was to not allow another task to take that resource while it's in use, not to allow switching while one uses a resources. Are you saying it's ok for task2 to lose it's "turn" until the next round when it completes the taks finally then releases the mutex?

Comment: "Priority inversion" is the name for the situation where a higher priority task is waiting for a resource owned by a lower priority task.  It's another problem you need to be aware of and handler with the mutex solution.  Some RTOSs have built-in ways to handle priority inversion.  For example, an RTOS may automatically raise the priority of the resource owner task up to the priority of the highest priority task waiting for the resource.  Search for "priority inversion" for more information.  Note that the alternate design described in the answer in not susceptible to priority inversion.

Comment: @user1452627 A couple more things: 1. "Priority inversion" is a non-issue for same priorities (so that's another way to avoid it).  2. There's also the possibility of deadlocks if using more than one mutex in random order.  To avoid deadlocks, they should only be used in either all-ascending or all-descending order.